# grub-install: error: cannot find efi directory. it's a rabbit hole

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, grub, uefi

I'm losing my sanity all I want to have is kali linux dual booted with win 10 but boot into kali, it directly goes to windows so im trying to manually install grub but I just can't get it to work, I've tried everything also I have no linux experience so I probably don't even know the most basic terms. I have gotten into ubuntu with a live usb or whatever and chose the option try ubuntu and you can just look at the picture now and help me out and this is like the 15th time I've gotten into ubuntu like this but still can't fix it please walk me through this, thanks.[image]

Comment: `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/boot/efi` - this creates a tree starting with `/mnt`. These directories don't magically show up from the thin air - you need to create them.

Comment: You can't use the `/dev/sdXN` device nodes from other people's documentation as-is unless your disks are configured and partitioned *exactly* as theirs. So please add the output of `lsblk -o +fstype,parttype` into your question. From the photo you attached, I can see that your `/dev/sdb` is probably the Ubuntu Live USB: you don't need to mount that again, you'll want to mount the partition(s) belonging to to the non-working Kali installation in order to fix it.

Comment: `please walk me through this` ... sadly, this site is not a tutorial forum ... it is a Q&A site ... if you are a linux beginner, then forget about kali ... get a user friendly distribution such as Mint or Ubuntu ... go to Kali when you have basic experience with debugging